# email protected in webscraping. how to get the text?

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape info from a website. The email is visible in web-browser but after using Requests and BeautifulSoup it shows `[email protected]`.

how to get the original text?

Here's my code below:

```py
for company_des in des_soup1.find_all('div',class_='flex medium-text fnt-14 align-item-center pointer'):
    print(company_des.text)
```

Screenshot is below:

[image]

HTML Source:

```html
<div class="margin-left-5"><a href="/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection" class="__cf_email__" data-cfemail="cea6aba2a2a18ea2a7a8baa7bae0a7a0">[email&#160;protected]</a></div></div>
```

Comment: html source code tag     ```<div class="margin-left-5"><a href="/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection" class="__cf_email__" data-cfemail="cea6aba2a2a18ea2a7a8baa7bae0a7a0">[email&#160;protected]</a></div></div>```

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow, kindly please edit your question and include that html source inside it. also share the url so we can verify. thanks, I believe that you are dealing with webiste which is behind `CloudFlare` which is actually protecting the `HTML` source from being scraped, is that the email ? `hello@liftit.in`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you are dealing with website which is behind `CloudFlare` or another firewall protection services.

Since you did not provided us with any more information regarding the website in order to check and verify.

So i can believe it's `Email Address Obfuscation` which you can read about it here [Click-Here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170016-What-is-Email-Address-Obfuscation-)

And regarding decoding the email address, so here's an solution for that.

```
def email(string):
    r = int(string[:2], 16)
    email = ''.join([chr(int(string[i:i+2], 16) ^ r)
                     for i in range(2, len(string), 2)])
    return email


print(email('cea6aba2a2a18ea2a7a8baa7bae0a7a0'))
```

Output:

```
hello@liftit.in
```